# CSS Webkit transition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, transform, transition

I'm kind of new to programming in Web and I'm stuck with a problem. I want to add a transition in my dropdown menu so that the menu itself pop from the bottom and disappear to the bottom. I've added this code with a translateY of 50px and an ease-in-out transition but the dropdown seems to be static...

HTML:

```
    <div class="right-menu list-inline no-margin-bottom">
    <div class="list-inline-item dropdown">
      <a id="settings" rel="nofollow" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link setting dropdown-toggle"><span class="d-none d-sm-inline-block"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i> Jean Dupont</span></a>
      <div aria-labelledby="settings" class="dropdown-menu">
        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span>Option 1</span></a>
        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span>Option 2</span></a>
        <a rel="nofollow" href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span>Option 3</span></a>
        <a rel="nofollow" id="logout" href="#" class="dropdown-item nav-link">Logout <i class="icon-logout"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-inline-item logout">
      <a href="#" id="logout" class="nav-link">Logout <i class="icon-logout"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
   nav.navbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu {

 -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
 transform: translateY(50px);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 

}

  nav.navbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu.active {

-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);

}

 nav.navbar .dropdown-item {

padding: 1rem !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #393c43;

}
```

Error seems to be here but I 'm not sure:

```
     -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
     transform: translateY(50px);
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
```

What should I fix ? Thanks!

Comment: remove the webkit it not used anymore

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer but I tried and it still doesnt work...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not with `-webkit-transform` or `-webkit-transition` , your animation works at first then stops working because bootstrap is modifying the `style` attribute in your `html` and it has more priority than the `css` in the `class` , so to overwrite the styling and the animation `bootstrap` provides you need to apply the styles in the `style` attribute of the `dropdown` ,

and modifying just the `trabslateY` won't work because you need to override the `translate3D`, those changes need to happen on the `show` and `hide` events of the `dropdown` and `bootstrap` uses `display:none` when hiding the `dropdwon` so you need to override that too and play with `opacity`

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().css({ 
        'transform' : 'translate3d(5px, 40px , 0px)',
        'visibility' : 'visible',
        'opacity' : 1
    });
});

$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {      
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().css({ 
        'transform' : 'translate3d(5px, 100px , 0px)',
        'display' : 'block',
        'visibility' : 'hidden',
        'opacity' : 0
    }, function(){ console.log('ended'); });
});
```

here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/19338/

Comment: Welcome :) , glad i could help